# MATLAB: Calculating AIC of a Linear Regression Model

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I have a matrix `X` with each row containing one training set, and each column containing unique features; and a vector `y` with each row containing respective responses (or solutions) for `X`. I can create a `Linear Model` like so:

`modl = fitlm(X,y)`

How can I calculate the AIC value for the above model? Unfortunately, the `aic()` function in matlab is not defined for linear models.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261273/how-can-i-apply-akaike-information-criterion-and-calculate-it-for-linear-regress) talking about AIC for the linear regression model. Is it something you are looking for?

Comment: yeah, that's what I had to use eventually. I was looking for any inbuilt matlab method that can do it for me. thanks anyways.